# PNG shadow shows as white border on android device

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, android

I am creating few icons with Drop shadow blending option in Photoshop. Then I save the icon as PNG with Transparency as 'chekced' and Matte as 'None'. The shadow looks fine on desktop but when my developer places those icons in his app, and runs on android device, all the shadows show as solid white border instead of transparent shadow. What changes should I make in my Photoshop settings to produce correct images?

Comment: A pretty basic question: does the software on the Android actually *support* transparency? (Because this is *exactly* what you would get if it does not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the place where you have the dynamic image, add a border tag to 0.

example -

```
border="0"
```

Comment: The images will be output on android app. the developer is doing native android development using Java. I think there is no border tag there.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "Save for web" and then choose png24 instead of png8 there. it would save your image transparency pixels more acuire.

Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If the image looks ok on your computer there's nothing wrong with the PNG file. Can you save the icon as a GIF instead, or does it offer to few colors?

Comment: GIF also looks fine on computer. But my developer says he is not able to render GIF on the android device. His other designer always gave him PNG only. Sorry, I am quite new to designing for android app. This is my first project.